# CSS transition depends on order of style assignments

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

Trying to make a container with text gradually expand upon adding new text to it, I used css `transition` property. Precisely, I fix current width, add text and then release the width. JS code is following:

```
footer.style['max-width'] = footer.offsetWidth + 'px'
footer.innerHTML += ' additional text'
footer.style['max-width'] = '500px'
```

with this css for `footer`:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: clip;
white-space: nowrap;
```

This did't work. Trying to find a workaround I added another line of code:

```
footer.style['height'] = footer.offsetHeight + 'px'
```

Now, with this line being put before assignment of `max-width` (so in the beginning of the snippet), it doesn't work. But putting it after that line (making it second line) — does. The question is why? and what is the proper way to work with transitions? (but mainly, why?)

Fiddle tested in firefox 40.0 and chrome 39.0: http://jsfiddle.net/53dbm6vz/

Comment: can you explain "*it doesn't work*"? (Using IE11, everything seems to *work*)

Comment: You are right, in IE it works. In other browsers what is see is one line getting full width instantly.

Comment: Try to initialize max-width to some sensible value (like offsetWidth for example..), and have the modification of the text & width occur at a later cycle, either as an event handler (button click for example), or using setTimeout. It's possible FF / Chrome are "ignoring" the intermediate value of max-width because it's inside the same JS cycle.

Comment: `max-width` is being initialized exactly to `offsetWidth`, it's the first line of the code I posted. And all that stuff was in `onclick` handler, I just reduced it here to post less js.

Comment: I see what meant now, `setTimeout(0)` helped indeed. Thank you. Rewrite your comment as an answer for me accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the problem is that both of your `footer.style['max-width']` assignments occur inside the same synchronous operation. The browser(s) probably ignore the intermediate value completely.

It can be resolved if you split the operation to 2 parts:

1. Set the initialization width and...
2. Use a `setTimeout` to trigger the actual assignment.

Try like this:

```
footer.style['max-width'] = footer.offsetWidth + 'px'
window.setTimeout(function() {
  footer.innerHTML += ' additional text'
  footer.style['max-width'] = '500px'
}, 0)
```